# ApexCharts in react legends not showing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I am trying to get some data in React.js using apexcharts.
I tried several approach but the legends are not coming.
i tried the docomentation for the apex charts, it is not showing enough info for the same.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactApexChart  from 'react-apexcharts';
const ChartUserManagement = () => {
    const [state,setData]=useState ({
      series: [44, 55, 67, 83],
            options: {
              chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'radialBar',
                toolbar: {
                  show: true
                },
                legend: {
                  show: true,
                  position: 'bottom' 
                },
              },
              
              plotOptions: {
                radialBar: {
                  dataLabels: {
                    name: {
                      fontSize: '22px',
                    },
                    value: {
                      fontSize: '16px',
                    },
                    total: {
                      show: true,
                      label: 'Total',
                      formatter: function (w) {
                        // By default this function returns the average of all series. The below is just an example to show the use of custom formatter function
                        return 249
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              labels: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Berries'],
            },

    })
    return (<div className='chart-dougnet-2'>
<ReactApexChart options={state.options} series={state.series} type="radialBar" height={170} />
    </div>   
    )
}
export default ChartUserManagement
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `legend` options are inside `chart` options. Add it for example after `labels` and it should work.

Your options look like this:

```
options:{
  chart:{
  ...
  legend: {...}
  },
  plotOptions: {...},
  labels: {...},
}
```

How it should be:

```
options:{
  chart:{...},
  plotOptions: {...},
  labels: {...},
  legend: {...}
}
```